# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_crontab'

Tags: python, django, cron, cron-task

I want to use crontab in Django to perform some scheduled tasks, but I'm encountering package import issues.I have already installed the crontab library, but when I add 'django_crontab' to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings file and start Django, it results in an error.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'systemserver.apps.SystemserverConfig',
    'corsheaders',
    'openApi.apps.openApiConfig',
    'django_crontab',
]
```

Here is the error report:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_crontab'
```

I tried this method, but it still doesn't work.

```
import os,django
 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "XXXX.settings")
django.setup()
```

Comment: are you using celery too?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your libraries with:

```
pip freeze
```

And you can use [django-cron](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io) instead of django-crontab.